# Ошибка парсера TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Много раз пользовался TCPDF для создания pdf'ок, всё было нормально...

Но тут возникла задача распарсить уже существующий тектовый pdf-файл...
в итоге при парсинге любого файла вылетает ошибка:

```
[Exception] 
TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: Invalid object reference: Array (0) /tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php:807
#0: TCPDF_PARSER->Error(string)   /tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php:680
#1: TCPDF_PARSER->getIndirectObject(string, string, boolean)   /tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php:286
#2: TCPDF_PARSER->decodeXrefStream(string, array)   /tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php:195
#3: TCPDF_PARSER->getXrefData()   /tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php:117
#4: TCPDF_PARSER->__construct(string)   /Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php:88
#5: Smalot\PdfParser\Parser->parseContent(string)   /Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php:74
#6: Smalot\PdfParser\Parser->parseFile(string)   /test.php:14
```

сначала думал что проблема в файлах, но не могут же куча попавшихся мне файлов иметь такую проблему

есть также подозрение что косяк в символами переноса (\n\r и \n) в файлах и неправильном их чтении, копаю сейчас в этом направлении, но пока без особых успехов.

как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Давно разобрался сам, напишу здесь может кому пригодиться:
проблема была в параметре [mbstring.func_overload](http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.overload.php) равным 2 — **TCPDF не может работать со строковыми функциями mb_str***, из-за них неправильно считывается разметка pdf-файла